# Custom UIControll target action is not called

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, uicontrol

I'm using [M13Checkbox](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox) and it doesn't sent any events to call my target action

```
let checkbox: M13Checkbox = {
    let checkbox = M13Checkbox()
    checkbox.cornerRadius = 1
    checkbox.boxType = .square
    checkbox.stateChangeAnimation = .bounce(.fill)
    checkbox.tintColor = UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 172/255, blue: 232/255, alpha: 1)
    checkbox.checkmarkLineWidth = 4
    checkbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkAction(_ :)), for: .valueChanged)
    return checkbox
}()

func checkMarkAction(_ sender: M13Checkbox) {
    print("M13CheckboxAction")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just moved this statement

```
checkbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkAction(_ :)), for: .valueChanged)
```

in `awakeFromNib()` method and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference the selector like this: `#selector(checkMarkAction:)` to match how it will appear to the Objective C runtime.

The target action pattern (and other dynamic features in Swift) is implemented on top of the Objective C runtime, so it's looking for the Objective C style name of your Swift method.

Comment: I get swift compiler error, I just tried to start a new test project and do the same, it's working! What can I do to fix problem with my project?

Comment: That's a lot of errors. :-) I would start by commenting out the line with the selector and then address any remaining issues. Once you've got things compiling, you can uncomment the line with the selector and hopefully be in a better position.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this ?

```
checkbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkAction), for: .valueChanged)
```